# How do I add a newline symbol in the middle of each triangle output, and without a newline symbol after the last triangle output?

Tags: c, printing, triangle

How do I add a newline between two triangles and without a newline at the end of the triangle?

Sample Input

```
4↵

5↵
```

Sample Output

```
*******↵

*****↵

  ***↵

*↵

↵

    *↵

   ***↵

  *****↵

 *******↵

*********↵
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printDownT(int n){
    for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++) {
        printf(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 1; k <= 2 * i - 1; k++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

    void printUpT(int n){
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++) {
        printf(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 1; k <= 2 * i - 1; k++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    int num;
    while (scanf("%d", &num) != EOF){
        if (num % 2 == 0){
            printDownT(num);
            printf("\n");
        }
        else{
            printUpT(num);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: you can also make the decision whether to print a newline *before* a triangle.

Comment: I do not get the problem. What is the desired output?

Comment: Just add «If (i > 1) » or «if (i < n)» before the print of \n

Answer (score 0):

Please see this code and note its creation and usage of character array `nlsym` (new line symbol).  Whenever you *do* want the new line symbol, include the printing of the `nlsym` array, and when you don't want it, you can omit the printing of the array as shown below.

Works nicely -- check the runnable code with output [here](https://godbolt.org/z/xaojMxba9).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char nlsym[]= {0xE2, 0x86, 0xB5, 0x0};

    printf("     %s\n", nlsym);
    printf("     *%s\n", nlsym);
    printf("    ***%s\n", nlsym);
    printf("   *****%s\n", nlsym);
    printf("  *******%s\n", nlsym);
    printf(" *********%s\n", nlsym);
    printf("***********\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
     ↵
     *↵
    ***↵
   *****↵
  *******↵
 *********↵
***********
```

This second example borrows upon your code to illustrate exactly how to integrate the `nlsym` array:
Runnable code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/P95sTqWc8).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printUpT(int n)
{
char nlsym[]= {0xE2, 0x86, 0xB5, 0x0};

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++) 
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 1; k <= 2 * i - 1; k++) 
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        if(i<n)
            printf("%s\n",nlsym);
        else
            printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    printUpT(7);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
      *↵
     ***↵
    *****↵
   *******↵
  *********↵
 ***********↵
*************
```

Comment: Sorry it's not working out the way that I expected, maybe I should descibe it more detail. Input an integer N (data type is Integer) and output a triangle using *. If N is an even number, please print the lower triangle. If N is an odd number, please print the upper triangle. And there's like ten input datas.

Comment: @user22881508 -- sorry to hear that things aren't working out.  Also sounds like a "newline symbol" was never really part of the problem?  That's interesting, and kind of funny too, because that is where I put the most effort, lol.  Well, you can always regroup, and open a new question stating the exact issues with more precision on your 2nd try.  It's OK, this happens all the time, and we're all learning here.  It's said that the "perfectly asked question almost answers itself" -- which is something for all of us to think about.